# Find the value of $x_{2014}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> A sequence of real numbers $(x_n)_n$ are defined as follows:
>   $$x_{n+2} = \frac{1 + x_{n+1}}{x_n}\quad n = 0, 1, 2,\dots$$ 
>   and $x_0 = 1$, $x_1 = 2$.
>
> Then $x_{2014}$ equals to
>
> (A) 1
>
> (B) 2
>
> (C) 3
>
> (D) none of the above

My attempts. here $x_0 =1$ and $x_1 = 2$, as $x_2 = (1 + x_1)/x_0  = (1 +2)/1 = 3$,  $x_3=(1+x_2)/x_1 = (1+3)/ 2 =2$... from this I can conclude that for even number sequence  I get value 3  and for odd number sequence I get the value 2. So 2014 is an even number so I get $x_{2014} =3$. So the correct option is  $3$...

Is its correct or not... pliz tel me the solution, I would be more thankful

Comment: Here's [a MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you calculate first few values of the sequence, you should get $$1,2,3,2,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,3,2,1,\ldots$$ and it is obvious that sequence is periodic, i.e. $x_n=x_{n\operatorname{mod}5} $, so $x_{2014} = x_4 = 1$.

If you want to be more rigourous, prove that $x_{n+5} = x_n$, for all $n$.

Comment: thanks a lots @ Ennar,,,but i can't able to show  xn+5 = xn for all n.

Comment: @lomber lego, just use definition of your sequence: $x_{n+5} = \frac{1+x_{n+4}}{x_{n+3}}$ and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is not correct. By evaluating more terms we get
$$x_0=1,x_1=2,x_2=3,x_3=2,x_4=1,x_5=1,x_6=2.$$
Note that $x_0=x_5$ and $x_1=x_6$ and since the recurrence of $x_n$ depends on the TWO previous terms, this shows that the sequence is periodic with period $5$. Now knowing the correct period you will be able to find $x_{2014}$.

Comment: thanks @Robert Z

Comment: @lomberlego $x_0=x_5$ and $x_1=x_6$ and the fact that the recurrence of $x_n$ depends on the TWO previous terms shows (by definition of the recurrence) that the sequence is periodic with period 5.

Comment: Robert, you are correct, but the missing keyword is induction. In this case, the step is $x_{n+5} = x_n$ and $x_{n+6} = x_{n+1}$ implies $x_{n+7} = x_{n+2}$. (@lomber lego)

Comment: thanks lots once again @Robert Z and @ Ennar.....

Comment: @lomber lego, appreciation on MSE is best shown by upvoting and/or accepting answer. Please consider accepting either Robert's or my answer, whichever you find more helpful.