# Is the given function is convex?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a convex function, i.e.,
>   $$f(tx + (1 − t)y) \leq  tf(x) + (1 − t)f(y)$$
>   for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $x, y \in\mathbb{R}$. 
>   Then which of the following is necessarily true?
>
> (A) $2f(0) + f(4) ≥ 2f(1) + f(2)$
>
> (B) $fg$ is a convex function whenever $g$ is convex
>
> (C) $f$ is nondecreasing
>
> (D) none of these

My attempt : For A) and B) I can't able to take counter example,  for option C) I take 
$f(x) = e^{-x}$  on $[0,\infty)$, as $f$ is showing the properties of convex,,so i can claim that $f$ is increasing that mean $f$ is non decreasing, so option C is the correct option.

Is my answer is correct or not, pliz help me and tell me the solution I would be more thankful.

Comment: For C) you actually showed a counterexample, since $e^{-x}$ is strictly decreasing. So C) is not true. An hint for B): linear (or affine) functions are always convex, so you could try using $f(x)=-x$ and a suitable $g$...

Comment: lomber lego, please start using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I've already given you the link [in your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2494687/find-the-value-of-x-2014) today, and I'm sure that you've already been directed there before. Typesetting mathematics in MathJax (and more generally, LaTeX) is a worldwide standard that anyone trying to communicate about mathematics should uphold.

Comment: @lomberlego Please Ennar's suggestion. Take a look to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. 
(A) The given inequality is equivalent to
$$ \frac{f(4)-f(2)}{4-2} \geq \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}.$$
Recall the main properties of convex functions [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable). You may also note that
$$f(0)+(f(0)+f(4))\geq f(0)+2f(2)=(f(0)+f(2))+f(2)\geq 2f(1)+f(2).$$

(B) $x$ and $-x$ are convex functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

(C) $e^{-x}$ is strictly decreasing and convex on $\mathbb{R}$. You may also  consider $x^2$ which is convex on $\mathbb{R}$. These are all counter-examples for option (C) which is not true (see also Lucio's comment above).

Comment: thanks a lot @ Robert Z ..ya..im getting that if f(x) ≥x^2 then it will convex but if f(x) ≤ x^2,,then it will not convex...im not getting much for   option B..Can u elaborate more option B.?

Comment: @lomber lego, why are you ignoring our plea to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? Is typing `$ f(x) \geq x^2 $` to produce $ f(x) \geq x^2 $ that hard?

Comment: @lomberlego I don't understand your comment. In (B) we are considering the product of two convex functions... Why are you using $\geq$ and $\leq$ (see our plea).

Comment: @ Ennar thanks ...next time ,,surely i will used maths jax

Comment: @Robert Z ,,, fg will not convex,,as u have  already  contradict in option c..am I right ?

Comment: @lomberlego $fg$ is not always convex because if you take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$ then the product $fg=-x^2$ is NOT convex.

Comment: @ Robert Z i got it,,once again thanks a lots for giving my answer....